# Can you change databases inside a SQL cursor?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, database-cursor

I have a cursor, inside a proc that is run from a db we use to store utilities. I need the cursor to dynamically change databases before is does the FETCH NEXT FROM /INTO @; part so that it loops through the correct rows in the correct database.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE utils.post_cohesity_restore

AS
Begin
    /* PURPOSE: re-attaches orphaned users and grants permissions after a Cohesity restore */

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE
        @juris char(20),
        @sql char(400),
        @sql_A char(400),
        @database sysname,
        @users char(20);
    
    SELECT 
        @database = destination_database_name   
    FROM 
        [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory]   
    WHERE 
        restore_date >= dateadd(DAY,-3,getDate()) 
        AND (LOWER(destination_database_name) LIKE '%clientdata%' 
        OR LOWER(destination_database_name) LIKE '%analysis%' 
        OR LOWER(destination_database_name) LIKE '%migration%')

    SELECT 
        @juris = LEFT(@database, 
        CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('ClientData', @database) <> 0 
            THEN (CHARINDEX('ClientData', @database)-1)
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Migration', @database) <> 0 
            THEN (CHARINDEX('Migration', @database)-1)
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Analysis', @database) <> 0 
            THEN (CHARINDEX('Analysis', @database)-1) 
        END)

    DECLARE users_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT 
            dp.[name] as username
        FROM sys.database_principals AS dp  
        LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp  
            ON dp.[name] = sp.[name]  
        WHERE 
            sp.sid <> dp.sid;

    OPEN users_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor INTO 
        @users;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = ('USE ' + @database 
            + '; ALTER USER ' + rtrim(@users) + ' WITH LOGIN = ' + rtrim(@users))
            PRINT @sql; -- for testing/seeing the EXEC below
            EXEC (@sql);
            FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor INTO 
                    @users;
        END;

    CLOSE users_cursor;

    DEALLOCATE users_cursor;
    
    SET @sql_A  = ('USE ' + @database 
            +  '; GRANT EXECUTE TO [analyst]; GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [analyst];' 
            + ' ALTER ROLE [ddladmin] ADD MEMBER [analyst];  ALTER ROLE [datawriter] ADD MEMBER [analyst];')
    
    PRINT @sql_A; -- for testing/seeing the EXEC below
    
    EXEC (@sql_A );

END
```

I need to switch to the db that populates @database right around this point so that the users end up being form that database.

```
DECLARE users_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT 
            dp.[name] as username
        FROM sys.database_principals AS dp  
        LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp  
            ON dp.[name] = sp.[name]  
        WHERE 
            sp.sid <> dp.sid;

    OPEN users_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor INTO 
        @users;
```

Any thoughts? It is even possible?

Comment: You can't change database context inside a user defined procedure, no. You could inside a dynamic statement, but not explicitly within the procedure.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: You should be *very* careful with the above though; it is *wide* open to injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up saving an edited version of the proc above in each database then creating an SSA job that a)identifies the database and b)calls that database's version of the proc.